# How to put ticks outside the plot in piecahrt ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

I want to put ticks and annotation text outside the piechart but it is not doing correctly.

Here is the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

cars <- data.frame(category = c("civic", "MG", "Suzuki", "Tesla"),
                   count = c (14810, 6457, 18233, 571),
                   percentage = c(37,16,46,1))

ggplot(cars, aes(x="", y=count, fill=category)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1, alpha = 0.5, color = "black") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
  geom_label_repel(data = cars,
                   aes(y = count, label = paste0(percentage, "%")),
                   size = 4.5, nudge_x = 1, show.legend = FALSE) +
  labs(fill = "Category") +
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = rainbow(4)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "right",
        text = element_text(family = "serif", colour = "black"))
```

[image]

But I want like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve your desired result you have to place the labels on the the boundaries using `x = 1.5`, where `1` is the "numeric" position of the x axis category `""` and `.5` accounts for (half) of the bar width.

Additionally, to align the labels and the slices of your pie you have to manually compute the positions if you want to use `nudge_x`. The reason is that in contrast to `geom_bar` a `geom_text(_repel)` will not use `position="stack"` by default but as you already use `position_nudge` (via `nudge_x`) you can't use `position_stack` to stack the labels.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(forcats)
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)

cars <- data.frame(
  category = c("civic", "MG", "Suzuki", "Tesla"),
  count = c(14810, 6457, 18233, 571),
  percentage = c(37, 16, 46, 1)
)

cars <- cars |>
  mutate(category = forcats::fct_inorder(category)) |> 
  arrange(desc(category)) |> 
  mutate(
    pos = cumsum(count),
    pos = .5 * (pos + lag(pos, default = 0))
  )

ggplot(cars, aes(x = "", y = count, fill = category)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1, alpha = 0.5, color = "black") +
  geom_label_repel(
    aes(x = 1.5, y = pos, label = paste0(percentage, "%")),
    size = 4.5, nudge_x = .5, show.legend = FALSE,
  ) +
  labs(fill = "Category") +
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = rainbow(4)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "right",
    text = element_text(family = "serif", colour = "black")
  ) +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0)
```

[image]